# Android Symbol can not be resolved in fullscreen Activity

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am using fullscreen activity and i am trying to read all .mp3 songs in it.
but when i importing :-

```
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
```

then its giving error can't resolve symbol android.

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Try looking at this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: Look at the first image, bottom left-ish there is an option to "launch standalone sdk manager". Click on that, and make sure all your build tools are up to date. Additionally scroll to the very bottom of the list in the standalone sdk manager. You should find the extras folder. Go through the folder and see if there is anything you can download that might be missing.